# Multiple foreach on if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to rerun task-sequences on multiple computers from a Drop-Down list that contains the task-sequences names,
and a computer list is loaded via a text file.

I tryed 2 diferent functions but the action isn't being triggered, no errors or output from ISE.

How can i achieve this?

```
#Removed #foreach ($Computer in $Computers)

#TaskSequences
$W10_PRELOAD_1809 = "W10_PRELOAD_1809"
$W10_UPG_1809 = "W10_UPG_1809"
$W10_UPG_1809_FORCE = "W10_UPG_1809_FORCE"

$Browse_OnClick = {
    $FileName = Select-FileDialog
    $Computers = Get-Content $FileName
    $Install.enabled = $true
}

$TaskSequence = "$W10_PRELOAD_1809", "$W10_UPG_1809", "$W10_UPG_1809_FORCE", "$W7_CHECK_PRELOAD", "$W7_1809_PRELOAD", "$W7_UPG_1809", "$W7_UPG_1809_FORCE"
$TaskSequence | % { $ListApps.Items.Add($_) }

$Install_OnClick= {

    if (!$ListApps.SelectedItem) {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a Task-Sequence from the drop down menu")

       }
    else {

        $TaskSequenceItem = $ListApps.SelectedItem.ToString()

      if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_PRELOAD_1809")
        {
           New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_PRELOAD_$Computer.txt -Force
        }

        if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_UPG_1809")
        {
             New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_UPG_$Computer.txt -Force
        }

        if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_UPG_1809_FORCE")
        {
          New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_Force_$Computer.txt -Force
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a script file, or run straight in Powershell? It's not clear how some of your variables (`$Computers`, `$ListApps`) are defined. I'd check there first if they are working in the foreach loop as you expect, and also not use `$TaskSequence` to hold different things in different places.  You may find it helpful to consult the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for guidance in making your question clearer. You may also want to consider using a switch statement instead of ifs here

Comment: Hello @sinaraheneba, the code tells that $Computers = Get-Content $FileName and $ListApps is a combobox/dropdown list to choose the task-sequence name. This is a Powershell GUI, Install_OnClick is the button that triggers the action

Comment: I understand that you are trying to build this functionality into a GUI and how you are trying to assign values to those variables, what I mean is that it is not clear from your example what those values actually are. If either of those aren't the values you are expecting, the `foreach` loops would not work as expected. Have you tested this on the command line to ensure the functionality works before putting it in your GUI?

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help, i'll try to provide an example of what i'm trying to do

$Computers = 'PC1','PC2'
$Fruits/"Drop-DownList"= 'Pears', 'Oranges'

          If Oranges are choosed from Drop-Down list, and you hit install button it creates a file named Oranges.txt in PC1 and PC2
          If Pears are choosed from Drop-Down list, and you hit install button ,it creates a file named Pears.txt in PC1 and PC2 Hope this helps :) The thing that i cannot achieve is to use 2 foreach statements, tried 2 diferent function like Install_OnClick and Install_OnClick2

Comment: The following code is working, performed tests creating a text file on a remote server for tests, this means that i can use the code i want for each action when Task-Sequence is choosed from the list. But i removed the most important part, to run this on multiple computers, or to create text files for each computer, this is the part that i cannot figure out how to make this run on multiple computers or to include the foreach statement when the Task-Sequences is choosed

Comment: Again, I understand what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure if you've checked the values of those variables are what you expect them to be. I would suggest trying to run these commands in powershell directly, step-by-step, seeing what they do and what values your variables contain, and making sure that it behaves at each step as you are expecting. If adding a `foreach` starts breaking things, chances are your variables did not contain the values you expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$Servers = Get-Content $FileName

ForEach ($Server in $Servers){

    if (!$ListApps.SelectedItem) {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a Task-Sequence from the drop down menu")

       }
    else {

        $TaskSequenceItem = $ListApps.SelectedItem.ToString()

      if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_PRELOAD_1809")
        {
            New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_PRELOAD_$Server.txt -Force

        }

        if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_UPG_1809")
        {
             New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_UPG_$Server.txt -Force
        }

        if ($TaskSequenceItem -eq "W10_UPG_1809_FORCE")
        {
          New-Item -Path \\emeamai-rs08\TEMP\Baseline_FMT\test_Force_$Computer.txt -Force
        }

    }
}
}
```